# How to install a custom control MS VS 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, custom-controls

I am using MS VS 2010.

I can not for the life of me find any instructions on how to install something like this to use on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I was wondering how to install and use this control in this version of MS VS with C#.

http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx

I am making a very dynamic page with a lot of post backs and I think this has great potential!

I need to know how to get this one working bolded below:

**Download (V2.2):**

- The sourcode is available in C# as a VS.NET project (Wont convert for
  me)
  **A ready-to-use assembly (including help file).** A demo shows the usage of this control.  Sourcecode for this Demo (C#) or Sourcode for
  the Demo (VB)

Any help would be greatly appreciated I can't find much information on this on the web. Perhaps I am using the wrong keywords...  I am stuck on this at work for the time being and no-one here can help. Its become one of those aggravating programming moments were the fun is wearing off!

I saw one other post on here "Install Custom Control in VS Toolbox" But he too has no luck and I wasn't really looking to install it with a program.  I swear I did this long ago with 2008 in college just through a process with MS VS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the assembly somewhere (we usually store them in an assemblies folder relative to the project), then add a reference to that assembly.

If the assembly supports being added to the toolbox, you can drag the assembly from windows explorer and drop it on the toolbox and it will automatically add all of the appropriate designable items to the toolbox. It is best, if you do this, to create a new tab to hold these items (right-click in the toolbox and select Add Tab).

If the assembly does support addition to the toolbox, your next step is to drag the item from the toolbox onto the page or control and visual studio should take care of wiring it up.

Otherwise, you will need to follow the instructions on the website or copy details from the sample projects to configure the control in your page.

Comment: good link here too, a little diff then yours.  You just Right click -> Choose Items -> under .net libraries you browse to the .dll

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366537.aspx